# Semantic UI dropdown selected item on page load

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to get Semantic UI's drop down to have a pre-selected option when the page loads in php as so but can't get it to be pre-selected any ideas?

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
              <input type="hidden" name="status">
              <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
              <div class="default text">Select status</div>
              <div class="menu">
                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="0") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="0">XXXX</div>
                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="1") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="1">YYYY</div>
                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="2") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="2">ZZZZ</div>
                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="3") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="3">QQQQ</div>  

                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="4") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="4">RRRRR</div>
                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="5") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="5">EEEEE</div>  
                <div class="<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="6") { echo "active ";} ?>item" data-value="6">DDDDD</div>        
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK needs to be initialised on document.ready :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.approved.dropdown')
<?php if ($profile['APPROVED']=="0") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Pending'); .dropdown('set value', '0'); ";}
if ($profile['APPROVED']=="1") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Registered'); .dropdown('set value', '1'); ";}
if ($profile['APPROVED']=="2") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Documents Submitted'); .dropdown('set value', '2'); ";}
if ($profile['APPROVED']=="3") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Processing'); .dropdown('set value', '3'); ";}
if ($profile['APPROVED']=="4") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Approved'); .dropdown('set value', '4'); ";}
if ($profile['APPROVED']=="5") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Approved - Photo Uploaded'); .dropdown('set value', '5'); ";}
if ($profile['APPROVED']=="6") { echo " .dropdown('set text', 'Completed'); .dropdown('set value', '6'); ";} ?>
 });
```